# Regex to pick days of the week from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a `csv` file that contains a column that looks like the following:

```
XYZ Mon-FR ABC
XY Mo-Fr AB
Xy M-F AbC
xyz MON-FRI ABC
XYZ Mon-Su ABC
XYZ Sat-Sun ABC
XXX SaSu ABC
XY MF & Sa ABC
```

Once I load the file, how can I extract - using regex in python - the days of week mentioned in each string such that I get another column with the following for each respective line above:

```
Monday-Friday
Monday-Friday
Monday-Friday
Monday-Friday
Monday-Sunday
Saturday-Sunday
Saturday-Sunday
Monday-Friday & Saturday
```

I can't seem to find a regex that caters for all possible differences as shown in the examples above.

Comment: Personally, I'd say your input file is just too flexible: `MF` or `Mon-Fr` or `Mo-Fr` or `M-F` or `MON-FRI` all mean the same. If, however, you do know that the cases you list are the *only* ones occurring, you might prefer to use a set of `str.replace` lines. That will be clearer than a regex that covers the all.

Comment: What is XYZ and ABC stand for? Is it numbers or text? If text, can it contain spaces or symbols similar to weekdays (ex. `Sat Sa Mon-Su Monday`)?

Comment: @akarilimano that could be circumvented by splitting on whitespace, removing the first and last items from the resulting list, and `str.join` the remaining elements together: `" ".join(field.split()[1:-1])`.

Comment: @Evert - there won't be much more variations from those but it could happen...

Comment: @akarilimano - they are text fields, but it cannot contain the weekday information...

Comment: @Evert your code returns `Sa Mon-Su` out of my example which is incorrect I think.

Comment: @akarilimano how is it incorrect: the first and last string are dropped, and from the OPs example, those strings appear to noise and should be ignored. What do you think the result should be?

Comment: @Evert OP said that XYZ and ABC are text fields, but we don't know if they contain spaces or not. Maybe `sample text Mon-Sat another text` should be reduced to `Monday-Saturday` then your code is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach using regular expressions should work:

```py
from itertools import chain
import csv
import re

days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
days_rep = [[day.lower()[:l] for l in xrange(len(day), 0, -1)] for day in days]
days_rep = sorted(chain.from_iterable([(len(day), day, index) for day in days] for index, days in enumerate(days_rep)), reverse=True)
days_d = {day : ' {} '.format(days[value]) for length, day, value in days_rep}
re_days = re.compile(r'({})'.format('|'.join(day for length, day, value in days_rep)), flags=re.I)

def normalise(entry):
    to_days = re_days.sub(lambda x: days_d[x.group(1).lower()], entry)
    return to_days.replace('  ', ' ').replace(' - ', '-').strip()

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    for cols in csv.reader(f_input):
        print "{} {} {}".format(cols[0], normalise(cols[1]), cols[2])
```

This assumes you have a `csv` file that looks as follows:

```
XYZ,Mon-FR,ABC
XY,Mo-Fr,AB
Xy,M-F,AbC
xyz,MON-FRI,ABC
XYZ,Mon-Su,ABC
XYZ,Sat-Sun,ABC
XXX,SaSu,ABC
XY,MF & Sa,ABC
```

It will display the following output:

```
XYZ Monday-Friday ABC
XY Monday-Friday AB
Xy Monday-Friday AbC
xyz Monday-Friday ABC
XYZ Monday-Sunday ABC
XYZ Saturday-Sunday ABC
XXX Saturday Sunday ABC
XY Monday Friday & Saturday ABC
```

The script works by first building a regular expression based on the days of the week in length order, starting as follows:

```
(wednesday|wednesda|thursday| .... mond|frid|wed|tue|thu|sun|sat|mon|fri|we|tu|th|su|sa|mo|fr|w|t|t|s|s|m|f)
```

This is used to lookup the corresponding full text in a dictionary. Lastly the formatting is fixed to remove extra spacing.

Comment: Martin thank you very much! Your code worked greatly! Just out of curiosity, why doesn't the last two rows of the output contain the dash '-' between the days of the week? Again, just keen to understand to what extent I can take this further... but it worked great! Thank you again!

Comment: The code doesn't add any dashes, so I suppose you would need to spot two adjacent days and add a dash manually on the output.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function that uses a set of replacements. It will be up to you to define the replacements, that is, make sure they are complete. A regular expression that covers all possibilities will likely become unreadable.

Thus, something like:

```
def alter(field):
    text = " ".join(field.split()[1:-1])
    text = text.replace("Mon-FR", "Monday-Friday")
    text = text.replace("Mo-Fr", "Monday-Friday")
    <etc>
    return text
```

If for a case like `XY MF & Sa ABC`, you're unsure about the amount of spacing around the `&` (making it harder to match the exact string), you can simply use an empty join-string in the first line: `"".join(...`.

If you have lots of cases where days and day-ranges are "and"-ed (`Mo-We & Fr & Sun`, for example, you may try and split by by the `&` and replace each subfield separately.